# Execute external file from Eclipse PDT?

Tags: eclipse, command-line, executable, eclipse-pdt

I would like to add button to toolbar or menu item to menu in Eclipse PDT to run external command line exe or bat file. How to do this in Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a custom "External Tools" run configuration.

Click on the button beside the Run button which looks the same as the Run button except it has a little red toolbox. Choose "External Tools Configurations" and create a new "Program" run configuration.